# New to Ubutu trying to play Linux version of Saints Row the Third and I get an error message

Tags: steam, 17.04

Trying to play steam games on Ubuntu 17.04 and I get [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxnZV.jpg) I am guessing I am missing dependencies but I don't know how to install them can someone help me. in case you need it my Graphics Card is a GTX 750Ti.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [edit] your question to *include* the error message in textual form.

Comment: I can't it won't let me copy and paste it.

Answer (score 1):

Try playing w/o the steam overlay

EDIT: At the request of Andrea, here is my response to your comment:

The problem that your error message indicates is that Saints Row 3, a 32 bit application, is trying to load the 64 bit steam overlay. To disable the steam overlay, do both of these things to make sure: -Go into Steam (top left corner of window) > Settings > In-Game > Uncheck the "Enable the Steam Overlay while in-game" box. -Right click on saints row 3 in your library and click properties, then uncheck the same box. If it still doesn't work after this, confirm that the error message is the same as before. If not, please post it, if so, tell me and I will try to help.

Comment: Do you think you could edit this answer to include instructions (or a link + a quote) on how to to do this on Ubuntu?

Comment: I found it but it still didn't work.

Comment: @SunsetSoda the problem that your error message indicates is that Saints Row 3, a 32 bit application, is trying to load the 64 bit steam overlay.  To disable the steam overlay, do both of these things to make sure:

-Go into Steam (top left corner of window) > Settings > In-Game > Uncheck the "Enable the Steam Overlay while in-game" box.

-Right click on saints row 3 in your library and click properties, then uncheck the same box.

If it still doesn't work after this, confirm that the error message is the same as before.  If not, please post it, if so, tell me and I will try to help.

Comment: @Derek, do not post answers in comments, please. Comments can get deleted any time. Consider editing your answer.